# How to checkout a remote git branch, on the remote machine?

Tags: git

I keep a simple set of [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org)-generated HTML files on a server, and I have decided to use git for version control.

I never edit files directly on the server, so I keep a branch checked out there on the server; when I make changes on my local copy, I commit and push; then I SSH to the server and merge it into the working copy there:

```
git push
ssh my-server.org "(cd /some/git/repo/ && git reset --hard)"
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?